# Fastest way to iterate over multiple list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops

I have the following code:

```
def func(value, start=None, end=None):
    if start is not None and start != 0:
        start = -start
    elif start == 0:
        start = None
    if end is not None:
        end = -end - 1
    return int('{:032b}'.format(value)[end:start], 2)

data = np.random.randint(1, 429496729, 10000)
starts = [10, 50, 100, 200]
stops = [30, 90, 170, 250]
data_dict = [{} for _ in range(len(starts))]

for ii, (start, stop) in enumerate(zip(starts, stops)):
    range_array = np.arange(start, stop, 2)
    data_dict[ii]['one'] = [func(value, 0, 8) for value in data[range_array]]
    data_dict[ii]['two'] = [func(value, 9, 17) for value in data[range_array]]
    data_dict[ii]['three'] = [func(value, 27, 27) for value in data[range_array]]
    data_dict[ii]['four'] = [func(value, 28, 28) for value in data[range_array]]
```

The problem is that this code runs through relatively slowly. However, all other approaches I have tried so far are even slower. Does anyone have an idea how to rewrite this code so that it runs through faster?

Comment: What do you define as ‘slowly’, and what increase are you looking to achieve?

Comment: You should not initialize a list of `dict`s as you did. All 4 dictionaries are the same object, check: `data_dict[0] is data_dict[1]`.

Comment: The problem is that I am calling this code multiple times, and to me it doesn't seem efficient to have so many list comprehensions iterating over the same array. However, if I get rid of these four comprehensions and use a nested loop, the runtime actually gets worse. In the best case, only one iteration over the data[range_array] would be necessary, reducing the time by a factor of 4?!

Comment: In your actual test, are `starts` and `stops` and `data` much much larger? Or is it just that you don't conceptually like what you are doing now?

Comment: @fsl In my actual script they are not the same. In the test script they are. I have to update the code.

Comment: @JonSG In the order of ```len(starts)``` approx 100. ```len(data)``` is in the order of 100000

Comment: @fsl - Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the code to get rid of that example error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy` broadcasting to vectorize the bitmasking with logical and `&` and shifting `>>`.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.randint(1, 429496729, 10000)
starts = [10, 50, 100, 200]
stops = [30, 90, 170, 250]

# equal to 'start' from calling func(value, start, end)
shift = np.array([0,9,27,28])[:, None]

# equal to 'end - start + 1' from calling func(value, start, end)
bitmask = np.array([9,9,1,1])[:, None]
  
d = [data[start:stop:2] >> shift & (2**bitmask - 1) for start, stop in zip(starts, stops)]
```

To access the result list *d*

```
d[0]
```

Output

```
array([[ 54, 227, 291, 281, 229,  59, 508,  87, 365, 416],
       [ 40, 207, 353, 168, 214, 271, 338, 268, 419,  52],
       [  1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   0]])
```

And access similar to your dictionarys

```
one, two, three, four = np.arange(4)
d[1][two]
```

Output

```
array([ 68, 479, 230, 295, 278, 455, 276,  45, 360, 488, 241, 336, 447,
       316, 181,  94, 138, 404, 223, 310])
```

---

To get the result exactly like the original solution:

```py
actual = [
    {
        name: x[index].tolist()
        for index, name
        in enumerate(["one","two","three","four"])
    }
    for x in d
]
```

This produces the exact result and maintains an order of magnitude boost in performance.

Comment: Note: This answer is more than an order of magnitude faster than the original according to `timeit`.

Comment: @JonSG - You raised a good point. I've updated the results of this solution with a `random.seed` to make it easier to compare results.

Comment: Agreed but I'm hoping that the downvote was not as a result of my prior suggestion that this did not produce a matching result. Which of course it does.